# CefSharp Zoom To Mid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, slider, cefsharp

I binded the `ZoomLevel`-Property of the `ChromiumWebBrowser` to a `Slider` in a UserControl.xaml. It works really good and its easy too, but its scrolls to the left upper corner of the browser.

```
    <Slider Minimum="0" Maximum="10" x:Name="Slider" />

    <cef:ChromiumWebBrowser ZoomLevel="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ElementName=Slider}" />
```

Do you know how to control the `ChromiumWebBrowser`-`ScrollViewer`or have a solution for this problem?

Comment: CefSharp doesn't use a scroll viewer. You might be able to send mouse wheel events, I've never tried, so it's an untested theory. Look at the source for an example sending mouse wheel events.

Comment: Allright so the Scrollbar is from Chromium right? Why do I want to send mousewheel events? Shouldnt i solve this in the browser with js?

Comment: If you can solve in JavaScript go for it